# Promise has "Variable declaration expected." error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm a new user of Promises in JavaScript and I have the following code snippet:

```
const arrayToTest;
let c = seasonalityService.getAnalysis(site, key)
    .then(function (result) {
        let date = moment();
        console.log(result.heating.getSeasonMonths(date));
        arrayToTest = result.heating.getSeasonMonths(date);
        console.log(result.cooling.getSeasonMonths(date));    

    })
    , function (error) {
        console.error('an error occured!!!', error);
    };
```

I have aService.js where I have `getAnalysis` method:

```
aService.getAnalysis = function (site, key) {
    return Promise.all([
        aService.heat(site, key),
        aService.cool(site, key)
    ]).spread(function (heating, cooling) {
        return { heating: heating, cooling: cooling };
    });
};
```

I tested the first part in similar situation and it worked fine but now before I compile the code if I hover over `function (error)` it says `[js] Variable declaration expected.`

I don't understand what variable does it need.

Comment: voted to close because it's a simply typographical error

Comment: `})` -> `}` and `};` -> `});`

Comment: `const arrayToTest;` without an initialiser expression is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

The message appears to relate to `const arrayToTest;`, which is illegal.

A `const` must be initialised at the point of declaration.

Read about `const` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
})
    , function (error) {
```

instead of

```
}
    , function (error) {
```

Comment: I used it like that somewhere else and it worked fine.

Comment: @migea no, it really didn't

Comment: Me too. Look at the closing bracket on line ')', after which you have a ', function() {'. Your comma ',' breaks the syntax.

Comment: it's not a syntax error per se, it is an error in **your** expected flow @migea - the `,` is in this case a `comma operator`. So what you think is the second argument to `.then` (the onRejeced callback) is actually a "standalone" and immediately discarded function expression